# Is QR code scanning necessary when coding a file sharing app that uses wifi direct

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I see that android wifi direct file sharing apps use QR scanning before establishing connection. Is this feature mandatory to include when coding your wifi direct file sharing app?

Answer (score 0):

No. Not necessary at all as I was working on a similar project. There is a Wifip2pManager API that could help you connect without using such a system.